# Xemian Xchange Api for Java, returning a default of 100 market orders

Tags: bitcoind, api, java, exchange-order

For sometime I am using this java API http://xeiam.com/xchange/ for building bitcoin trading robots. Today I got a bit stuck and I wanted to see if somebody had the same issue before.

I call the order books like this:

```
OrderBook orderBook = exchangeMarket.getExchange().getPollingMarketDataService().
                                getOrderBook(CurrencyPair.LTC_BTC, new int[] {20});
```

My problem is that the orderBook object contains 100 asks and 100 bids. I just want 20. Does anybody know why this is not returning the amount I pass in the second parameter? BTW, if I try 150, it also returns 100. I don't know how to modify the amount of returned elements.

Comment: The [xchange docs](http://xeiam.com/javadocs/xchange/com/xeiam/xchange/service/polling/marketdata/PollingMarketDataService.html) say that the meaning of getOrderBook's second argument is exchange-specific. Does the exchange you're polling support limits? Do they support them in the manner that you're using them?

Comment: @Nick ODell I am interested in the exchanges Cryptsy and BTCE, but I am not sure how to find if they support limits. Also if they do support, how do I pass the parameter? I tried different things like new Integer[]{20,20}... but nothing worked, I would like to confirm that indeed there is no such support in those exchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cryptsy driver does not support this, or any kind of argument, actually.

https://github.com/timmolter/XChange/blob/df9eb4e4d95c5bb3954b1527f585d9238514fa94/xchange-cryptsy/src/main/java/com/xeiam/xchange/cryptsy/service/polling/CryptsyPublicMarketDataService.java#L39

Neither does BTCE.

https://github.com/timmolter/XChange/blob/df9eb4e4d95c5bb3954b1527f585d9238514fa94/xchange-btce/src/main/java/com/xeiam/xchange/btce/v2/service/polling/BTCEMarketDataService.java#L55

However, the BTCE `getTrades` method does support a limit argument.

https://github.com/timmolter/XChange/blob/df9eb4e4d95c5bb3954b1527f585d9238514fa94/xchange-btce/src/main/java/com/xeiam/xchange/btce/v2/service/polling/BTCEMarketDataService.java#L78